# Same .net webservice with different configuration value

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice which is hitting a particular reporting server "xyz".
Now we have added a new reporting server and this same webserver is supposed to hit this new reporting server "abc". We need to make it point to this new reporting server with minimal changes (or possibly no code change in webservice). Now, which reporting server to hit will be determined by the client.

To add this new reporting server we will have to add a new configuration value set in the WebService and this would mean making code changes in the webservice.

To avoid it we thought of creating a new website (for this webservice) in the same IIS (replicated instances of the same webservice) with different configuration value. However I wanted to know what is the recommended approach to such scenario? Also please note there will not be more additional reporting servers.

Comment: Given the new requirement of "Now, which reporting server to hit will be determined by the client" I can't see how you can do this without changing code (which is probably pretty minimal anyway). You need your code to be able to receive the client's choice and adjust. Config or deployment changes will only allow you to statically point at the report server.

Comment: Are you saying you are now broadcasting your same message from client to multiple web service? Is it OneWay Message?

Comment: The web service accepts the required parameters (such as report name / report parameters / report server Name) and connects to the report server and executes certain APIs that are exposed by the reporting server to call the particular report. It ex3ecutes the report and generates a PDF file and stores it in a pre-defined shared folder Name. Now, we are adding a new report server and also adding a new client which will call this webservice.

Comment: So what we are planning is to have this webservice sit on this new reporting server box. This will eliminate and traffic issues faced by the original instance (webservice) and this new instance will be separate from the original instance. 
Also having this approach will only require us to change the config file and the resat of everything remains the same.